# Javainterface as generalized objecttype Concept in C++

Tags: c++, interface

I want to use a abstract class as Interface in C++ for reasons :) like this:

```
    class Base{
    public:
        virtual bool foo() = 0;
        int getValue() {return this->value;};

        int compare(Base other) {
            //calculate fancy stuff using Base::foo() and other given stuff through inheritance
            return result;
        }

    protected:
        int value;
    };

    class TrueChild: public Base{
    public:
        TrueChild(int value): Base() { this->value = value;}
        bool foo() {return 1;}
        //do stuff with value
    };

    class FalseChild: public Base{
    public:
        FalseChild(int value): Base() { this->value = value;}    
        bool foo() {return false;}
        //do other stuff with value
    };
```

But I can't pass Base as type in the compare method because it's a abstract class and I can't instantiate it. C++ complains with `cannot declare parameter ‘first’ to be of abstract type ‘Base’` . How can I create a method that takes params with type of any class, which implements the Base class?

I know it is kind of similar to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974609/interface-in-cpp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323595/best-way-to-declare-an-interface-in-c11) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216750/how-can-i-simulate-interfaces-in-c), but these answers don't help, because they doesn't talk how to use the Interface as generalized type in any way.

Thank you :)

Comment: Don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  Any good C++ book would have explicitly have the `Base` parameter as a reference or pointer, not an object.

Comment: I don't know where `first` is but you are passing an object instead of a reference or pointer to an object.

Comment: okay, if i use a reference It works. what do I return if I want to return the "bigger" object for example? do i have to use ```template <typename T>```  then?

Comment: First understand that  C++, something exists that doesn't exist in Java  -- *object slicing*.  You cannot return or pass a base class, and in the caller, have the full object available.  The reason is that the derived portion of that object has been "sliced off" -- you're trying to stuff 10 pounds of potatoes in a 5 pound bag..  You return a `Base` object, you're going to get a `Base` object -- you pass a `Base`,object you're passing a `Base` object.  You can't cast to a derived object as you would in Java from a Base object.

Comment: is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int compare(Base const& other);
```

Which you would then use as:

```
trueChild.compare(falseChild);
```

Comment: Or pass by reference.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Updated the answer.